# angularjs factory service array data empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

hi i'm beginner in angular, i want to know why i'm getting an empty array when  i call it out of my service,  this is my code :

```
 var app = angular.module("myModule", ['ngResource']);


   app.controller("myController", function ($scope,$http,$log,myService) {


    $scope.users = []:

     myService.query(function(data) {

        $scope.users=data;

       // all is fine, the length is 10 obj
        console.log("users in: "+$scope.users.length);

      });

     //here i want to use my $scope.users array but the length is 0
     console.log("users out: "+$scope.users.length);


});
```

any idea on how to deal with this issue
thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you seeing `users out` appear before `user in` in the log?

Comment: You can't do that... `$resource` uses ajax which is asynchronous. You have to use the data in the callback. You are trying to eat a pizza before it is actually delivered

Comment: hi @sebastianForsberg , exactly i see the users out before the user in

Comment: @charlietfl , please do you have an example on how to use the data in the callback

Comment: really depends on what you are trying to do

Comment: thank you @charlietfl for your time , i want to do something like that : var mydata = $scope.users;

Comment: why? You already have $scope.users

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116898/discussion-between-ali-and-charlietfl).